# JPA inheritance mapping gives no error, but JPQL query not giving any results

Tags: java, jpa, javafx, properties, mapping

I have a class Persoon:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persoon")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Type")
public class Persoon implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected Persoon() {

}

protected Persoon(String naam, String voornaam, String mail) {
    setNaam(naam);
    setVoornaam(voornaam);
    setEmail(mail);
}

private final StringProperty naam = new SimpleStringProperty();

@Column(name = "Naam")
public String getNaam() {
    return naam.get();
}

public void setNaam(String value) {
    naam.set(value);
}

public StringProperty naamProperty() {
    return naam;
}
@Column(name = "Voornaam")
public String getVoornaam() {
    return voornaam.get();
}

public void setVoornaam(String value) {
    voornaam.set(value);
}

public StringProperty voornaamProperty() {
    return voornaam;
}

private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

@Id
@Column(name = "Email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email.get();
}

public void setEmail(String value) {
    email.set(value);
}

public StringProperty emailProperty() {
    return email;
}
...
```

Which has a subclass JobCoach:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("JobCoach")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class JobCoach extends Persoon implements Serializable {

private final StringProperty organisatie = new SimpleStringProperty();

@Column(name = "NaamBedrijf")
public String getOrganisatie() {
    return organisatie.get();
}

public void setOrganisatie(String value) {
    organisatie.set(value);
}

public StringProperty organisatieProperty() {
    return organisatie;
}
...
```

This maps perfectly but when I run JPQL in netbeans (rightclicking on persistence.xml), it returns 0 results.

The table 'persoon' in my schema however *does* have a row:

[image: row]

Where is my error here?

select p from persoon p WHERE p.Type="JobCoach" also wont work.

Answer (score 0):

use `select p from Persoon p WHERE .....` JPA refer entity class name not table name.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo in my question. Select p from Persoon p returns 0 results is my issue.